Should "hardware" only pertain to "mining hardware" or should this include payment kiosks?
In the spectrum of hardware that does, or could exist with Bitcoin, should hardware be an all encompassing tag, or should there be some kind of separation between

mining
hardware wallets / 2FA
merchant/payment kiosks


I didn't realize that was a tag. Kill it. Kill it with fire.
Retag hardware questions like so:

mining hardware becomes mining-hardware
hardware wallet becomes hardware-wallet
ATM becomes bitcoin-atm
Point of sales systems/kiosks become point-of-sale
"How much hardware do I need to run a Bitcoin node?" gets no hardware tag at all.

I've already started. Tag is gone. 

for the fourth: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-of-sale? ;)
